# Ping Pong game in pygame

Tags: python, performance, pygame

I wrote a very simple Ping Pong game using pygame and everything worked out quite well. The only issue is the high CPU usage, which seems a bit strange. One thread is immediately occupied up to 100% after starting the application.

I am currently using a `pygame.clock` and `clock.tick(30)` inside my main loop. Therefore, pygame shouldn't occupied as many CPU cycles as possible. Additionally, I replaced the use of `pygame.event.get()` (sometimes mentioned as a [potential bottleneck](https://uniformlyuninformative.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/python-chess-v-07-lowering-pygames-cpu-usage/)), which did not change the CPU usage.

main.py

```
import pygame
from colors import *
from ball import Ball
from racket import Racket
from directions import Directions
from player import Player

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
MAX_SCORE = 5
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, 0, 32)

DONE = False
FPS = 30

left_player = Player(Directions.LEFT, 'Left')
right_player = Player(Directions.RIGHT, 'Right')

curr_ball = Ball(screen, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)

left_racket = Racket(screen, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, Directions.LEFT)
right_racket = Racket(screen, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, Directions.RIGHT)

rackets = pygame.sprite.Group()
rackets.add(left_racket)
rackets.add(right_racket)
stuff_to_draw = pygame.sprite.Group()
stuff_to_draw.add(left_racket)
stuff_to_draw.add(right_racket)


def game_over(screen, winner, left_paper, right_player):
    gray_overlay = pygame.Surface((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    gray_overlay.fill(GRAY)
    gray_overlay.set_colorkey(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(gray_overlay, BLACK, [0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT])
    gray_overlay.set_alpha(99)
    screen.blit(gray_overlay, (0, 0))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    game_over = font.render('{} Player WINS!'.format(winner.name), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(game_over, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 300, WIN_HEIGHT / 2 - 100))
    scoreline = font.render(
        '{} - {}'.format(left_paper.score, right_player.score), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(scoreline, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 50, WIN_HEIGHT / 2 + 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(2000)

while not DONE:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            DONE = True

    pygame.event.pump()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_q]:
        DONE = True
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        right_racket.move_up()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        right_racket.move_down()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        left_racket.move_up()
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        left_racket.move_down()

    stuff_to_draw.update()
    curr_ball.update()

    col_left, col_right = curr_ball.rect.colliderect(left_racket.rect), curr_ball.rect.colliderect(right_racket.rect)
    if col_right == 1 or col_left == 1:
        curr_ball.toggle_direction()
        curr_ball.hit()

    if curr_ball.get_x_val() <= 0:  # left border
        right_player.score = 1
        curr_ball = Ball(screen, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
    elif curr_ball.get_x_val() >= WIN_WIDTH:  # right border
        left_player.score = 1
        curr_ball = Ball(screen, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)

    # Print scores
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 25)

    left_player_score = font.render(
        '{}'.format(left_player.score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    right_player_score = font.render(
        '{}'.format(right_player.score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    goal_text = font.render(
        '{}'.format(MAX_SCORE), True, (255, 255, 0))

    screen.blit(left_player_score, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 100, 10))
    screen.blit(right_player_score, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 + 100, 10))
    screen.blit(goal_text, (WIN_WIDTH / 2, 0))

    stuff_to_draw.draw(screen)
    curr_ball.draw(screen)

    if left_player.score >= MAX_SCORE:
        game_over(screen, left_player, left_player, right_player)
    elif right_player.score >= MAX_SCORE:
        game_over(screen, right_player, left_player, right_player)

    if left_player.score >= MAX_SCORE or right_player.score >= MAX_SCORE:
        DONE = True

    pygame.display.set_caption('Ping Pong '+ str(clock.get_fps()))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

colors.py

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GRAY = (64, 64, 64)
```

ball.py

```
import pygame
import random
from colors import *
from directions import *


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.direction = random.choice([Directions.DOWN_LEFT, Directions.DOWN_RIGHT, Directions.UP_LEFT, Directions.UP_RIGHT])
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, WHITE, [0, 0, 10, 10])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = (width / 2 + 2, height / + 2)
        self.hits = 0
        self.speed_up = 1.0

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def hit(self):
        self.hits += 1
        self.speed_up = 1.0+self.hits/10

    @property
    def position(self):
        return (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

    @position.setter
    def position(self, pos):
        try:
            pos_x, pos_y = pos
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Pass an iterable with two items")
        else:
            self.rect.x, self.rect.y = pos_x, pos_y

    def up_left(self):
        self.position = (self.position[0] - 10*self.speed_up, self.position[1] - 10*self.speed_up)

    def up_right(self):

        self.position = (self.position[0] + 10*self.speed_up, self.position[1] - 10*self.speed_up)

    def down_left(self):

        self.position = (self.position[0] - 10*self.speed_up, self.position[1] + 10*self.speed_up)

    def down_right(self):

        self.position = (self.position[0] + 10*self.speed_up, self.position[1] + 10*self.speed_up)

    def update(self):
        if self.position[1] <= 10:  # upper border
            self.direction = random.choice(
                [Directions.DOWN_LEFT, Directions.DOWN_RIGHT])
        if self.position[1] >= self.height - 10:  # bottom border
            self.direction = random.choice(
                [Directions.UP_LEFT, Directions.UP_RIGHT])

        options = {Directions.UP_LEFT: self.up_left,
                   Directions.UP_RIGHT: self.up_right,
                   Directions.DOWN_LEFT: self.down_left,
                   Directions.DOWN_RIGHT: self.down_right,
                   }
        options[self.direction]()

    def toggle_direction(self):
        if self.direction == Directions.DOWN_LEFT:
            new_direction = Directions.DOWN_RIGHT

        if self.direction == Directions.DOWN_RIGHT:
            new_direction = Directions.DOWN_LEFT

        if self.direction == Directions.UP_RIGHT:
            new_direction = Directions.UP_LEFT

        if self.direction == Directions.UP_LEFT:
            new_direction = Directions.UP_RIGHT

        try:
            self.direction = new_direction
        except NameError:
            pass

    def get_x_val(self):
        return self.rect.x
```

racket.py

```
import pygame
from colors import *
from directions import *


class Racket(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen, width, height, side):
        super().__init__()

        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.racket_height = 100
        self.movement_speed = 20
        offset = 20
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, self.racket_height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, WHITE, [0, 0, 10, self.racket_height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        print(side)
        if side is Directions.LEFT:
            self.position = (offset, self.height / 2)
        else:
            self.position = (self.width - offset - 10, self.height / 2)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

    @position.setter
    def position(self, pos):
        try:
            pos_x, pos_y = pos
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Pass an iterable with two items")
        else:
            self.rect.x, self.rect.y = pos_x, pos_y

    def move_up(self):
        if self.position[1] > 0:
            self.position = (self.position[0], self.position[1] - self.movement_speed)

    def move_down(self):
        if self.position[1] + self.racket_height < self.height:
            self.position = (self.position[0], self.position[1] + self.movement_speed)
```

directions.py

```
from enum import Enum


class Directions(Enum):
    UP_LEFT = 7
    UP_RIGHT = 9
    DOWN_LEFT = 1
    DOWN_RIGHT = 3
    LEFT = 4
    RIGHT = 6
```

player.py

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self, side, name):
        self.side = side
        self.points = 0
        self.name = name

    @property
    def score(self):
        return self.points

    @score.setter
    def score(self, val):
        self.points += val
```

Comment: Please post the complete project, otherwise we can't run and profile the game.

Comment: Sorry. Now all the files are included.

Comment: I've just run and profiled the program and the performance doesn't seem to be bad. Is your hardware relatively old? Pygame uses only software rendering, so it's rather slow, but a simple game as Pong should run without problems. The only thing that you shouldn't do is, instantiating a new `font` object each frame (do it once before the while loop).

Comment: Give FPS a small value, like 2. Verify you have idle CPU cycles. Keep bumping it up until you saturate a core, and then you at least know how big a change the code will require. BTW, you didn't mention which thread was pegged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your performance problems, but I've got some suggestions for other improvements.

If you give the `Ball` class a dictionary similar to the `options` dict you can reduce the `toggle_direction` method to one line.

```
# In the __init__ method.
self.direction_dict = {
    Directions.UP_LEFT: Directions.UP_RIGHT,
    Directions.UP_RIGHT: Directions.UP_LEFT,
    Directions.DOWN_LEFT: Directions.DOWN_RIGHT,
    Directions.DOWN_RIGHT: Directions.DOWN_LEFT,
    }

# And then just set direction to the new direction.
def toggle_direction(self):
    self.direction = self.direction_dict[self.direction]
```

(You can define `self.options` in the `__init__` method as well.)

However, I'd rather get rid of the `Directions` enum and these dicts and **use [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) for the direction and positions** instead. To move the ball you can just add its `self.direction` vector times the `self.speed_up` to the `self.position` and then update the `self.rect`. So the class could be written in this way:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        """Reset the attributes of the ball."""
        self.direction = random.choice(
            [Vector2(-10, -10), Vector2(10, -10),
             Vector2(-10, 10), Vector2(10, 10)])
        self.position = Vector2(WIN_WIDTH/2, WIN_HEIGHT/2)
        self.rect.center = self.position
        self.hits = 0
        self.speed_up = 1.0

    def hit(self):
        self.hits += 1
        self.speed_up = 1.0 + self.hits/10

    def update(self):
        if self.position.y <= 10:  # upper border
            self.direction = random.choice([Vector2(-10, 10), Vector2(10, 10)])
        if self.position.y >= self.height - 10:  # bottom border
            self.direction = random.choice([Vector2(-10, -10), Vector2(10, -10)])

        self.position += self.direction * self.speed_up
        self.rect.center = self.position
```

---

I'd **fuse the `Player` and `Racket` classes**, since `Player` is just a container for some values and has got no methods, so using a class is unnecessary. But if you later want to add more logic you can keep them apart.

---

In Python **you mostly don't need properties or getter and setter methods** and can just assign or increment the attributes like `score` directly. You only need properties if you later have to add code that needs to be executed during the attribute access. The try...excepts are not really needed in your property methods.

---

Put all the sprites into a sprite group, so that you don't have to update and draw them separately in the main loop.

---

Don't instantiate `pygame.SysFont` each frame.  Just define `font = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 25)` somewhere before the while loop.

---

Put your code into a main function and call it in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause, so that it doesn't run if the module gets imported. Leave only the constants in the global scope not the variables.

---

`pygame.event.pump` is not needed because you already have an event loop that clears the event queue.

---

Here's a complete example:

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()

FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 25)
FPS = 30
WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
MAX_SCORE = 5
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (64, 64, 64)


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        """Reset the attributes of the ball for a restart.

        Called when the ball leaves the screen and a player scores.
        """
        self.direction = random.choice(
            [Vector2(-10, -10), Vector2(10, -10),
             Vector2(-10, 10), Vector2(10, 10)])
        self.position = Vector2(WIN_WIDTH/2, WIN_HEIGHT/2)
        self.rect.center = self.position
        self.hits = 0
        self.speed_up = 1.0

    def hit(self):
        self.hits += 1
        self.speed_up = 1.0 + self.hits/10

    def update(self):
        if self.position.y <= 10:  # upper border
            self.direction = random.choice([Vector2(-10, 10), Vector2(10, 10)])
        if self.position.y >= self.height - 10:  # bottom border
            self.direction = random.choice([Vector2(-10, -10), Vector2(10, -10)])

        self.position += self.direction * self.speed_up
        self.rect.center = self.position


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, side, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.racket_height = 100
        self.movement_speed = 20
        offset = 20
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, self.racket_height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        if side == 'Left':
            self.position = Vector2(offset, self.height/2)
        else:
            self.position = Vector2(self.width-offset-10, self.height/2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=self.position)

    def move_up(self):
        if self.position.y > 0:
            self.position.y -= self.movement_speed
            self.rect.top = self.position.y

    def move_down(self):
        if self.position.y + self.racket_height < self.height:
            self.position.y += self.movement_speed
            self.rect.top = self.position.y


def game_over(screen, winner, left_paper, right_player):
    gray_overlay = pygame.Surface((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    gray_overlay.fill(GRAY)
    gray_overlay.set_colorkey(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(gray_overlay, BLACK, [0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT])
    gray_overlay.set_alpha(99)
    screen.blit(gray_overlay, (0, 0))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    game_over = font.render('{} Player WINS!'.format(winner), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(game_over, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 300, WIN_HEIGHT / 2 - 100))
    scoreline = font.render(
        '{} - {}'.format(left_paper.score, right_player.score), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(scoreline, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 50, WIN_HEIGHT / 2 + 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(2000)


def render_score(left_player, right_player, font):
    """Render player scores onto surfaces."""
    left_player_score = font.render(str(left_player.score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    right_player_score = font.render(str(right_player.score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    return left_player_score, right_player_score


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, 0, 32)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    left_player = Player('Left', WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
    right_player = Player('Right', WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
    curr_ball = Ball(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(left_player, right_player, curr_ball)

    goal_text = FONT.render(str(MAX_SCORE), True, (255, 255, 0))
    left_player_score, right_player_score = render_score(
        left_player, right_player, FONT)

    done = False

    while not done:
        # Event handling.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_q]:
            done = True
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            right_player.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            right_player.move_down()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            left_player.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            left_player.move_down()

        # Game logic.
        all_sprites.update()
        # Determine winner.
        if left_player.score >= MAX_SCORE or right_player.score >= MAX_SCORE:
            # This is a conditional expression (similar
            # to a ternary in other languages).
            winner = 'Left' if left_player.score > right_player.score else 'Right'
            game_over(screen, winner, left_player, right_player)
            done = True

        # Collision detection with the rackets/players.
        col_left = curr_ball.rect.colliderect(left_player.rect)
        col_right = curr_ball.rect.colliderect(right_player.rect)
        if col_right or col_left:
            curr_ball.direction.x *= -1  # Reverse the x component of the vectow.
            curr_ball.hit()

        if curr_ball.rect.x <= 0:  # left border
            right_player.score += 1
            curr_ball.initialize()
            left_player_score, right_player_score = render_score(
                left_player, right_player, FONT)
        elif curr_ball.rect.x >= WIN_WIDTH:  # right border
            left_player.score += 1
            curr_ball.initialize()
            left_player_score, right_player_score = render_score(
                left_player, right_player, FONT)

        # Drawing.
        screen.fill((30, 30, 70))
        screen.blit(left_player_score, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 - 100, 10))
        screen.blit(right_player_score, (WIN_WIDTH / 2 + 100, 10))
        screen.blit(goal_text, (WIN_WIDTH / 2, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.set_caption('Ping Pong {}'.format(clock.get_fps()))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It would be nice to know if this improved the performance as well.  Would using a Sprite Group give some improvement, aside from the other (more marginal?) improvements outlined above?

Comment: I think the changes have hardly any effect on the performance. Both the original and the changed version run fine on my machine. The only  thing that affected the performance in a negative way was the continuous creation of `SysFont` objects in the main loop, but that was only a minor problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed code review. You (@skrx) brought out some important aspects to my attention. I issued the post mainly because i thought  the event handling could be a bottleneck and my CPU fan immediately starts running the moment i start the application.  
I accepted your answer since it helped me a lot and the performance, by all appearances, cannot be further improved.

Comment: I'm still wondering why you have this CPU problem. Does my example also cause 100% CPU usage? BTW, which Python and pygame version and operating system do you use? And how do you run the game?

Comment: Regarding the review, I forgot to mention that I only rerender the score surfaces when one player scores now (but that's also just a minimal optimization). And I'd actually use a `Game` class with separate `handle_events`, `run_logic` and `draw` methods instead of the `main` function. There's an [example in Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=game_class_example.py).

Comment: The CPU usage did not change noticeable compared to the original version. I am executing the game using python3.5 on a linux mint directly through the CLI (pygame should be the current version). Nonetheless i gained a lot from your answer! The separation which is portrayed in your link looks very good. 
(BTW, sorry for my late response.)

Comment: Do you know how to profile a program with the help of [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in pygame. Check out the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160971/pygame-full-core-usage-in-simple-loop).

Comment: That's very interesting - let's hope the bug will be fix in the next release. (Btw: i have no experience with cProfile so far)

Answer (score 1):

A simplification:

```
def toggle_direction(self):
    if self.direction == Directions.DOWN_LEFT:
        new_direction = Directions.DOWN_RIGHT

    if self.direction == Directions.DOWN_RIGHT:
        new_direction = Directions.DOWN_LEFT

    if self.direction == Directions.UP_RIGHT:
        new_direction = Directions.UP_LEFT

    if self.direction == Directions.UP_LEFT:
        new_direction = Directions.UP_RIGHT

    try:
        self.direction = new_direction
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Should be:

```
def toggle_direction(self):
    if self.direction == Directions.DOWN_LEFT:
        self.direction = Directions.DOWN_RIGHT

    elif self.direction == Directions.DOWN_RIGHT:
        self.direction = Directions.DOWN_LEFT

    elif self.direction == Directions.UP_RIGHT:
        self.direction = Directions.UP_LEFT

    elif self.direction == Directions.UP_LEFT:
        self.direction = Directions.UP_RIGHT
```

This is completely equivalent but simpler and avoids an exception handling call.